# Duplicate text in label to make it like 3d in c#. net framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, text, label

I am doing a menu like the following in c# for a school small game.

[image]

I am using the labels to create this, but how can I do that orange color behind it? The only solution I see, is exporting that text as png and use it as image instead of label. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What Framework version, what UI Framework? Is it UWP, WPF, Winforms or something else? Are you _actually_ on .Net **Framework** or on .Net 6 or even 7 ?

Comment: The above comment is very important as the only possible way to do this with labels is to have custom [text renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

Comment: You may find this enlightning: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/creating-text-labels-with-a-drop-shadow-effect-in-windows-forms/ba-p/228428

Comment: For .Net Framework and WPF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-text-with-a-shadow?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: ^^ I googled: "WinForms Label Text rendering with shadow"

Comment: @Fildor yeah, I did the same, but the real question is here does he use win forms? I assume he does but who knows?

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist Right. Only OP can clear that up. I just wanted to drop one or two _potentially_ helpful things until he does.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. I am using windows forms. I will try something like that then.

Comment: The literature I have read recently is helpful to you: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/creating-text-labels-with-a-drop-shadow-effect-in-windows-forms/ba-p/228428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export that text as a png and use it as an image, or you can style it with a label. But using labels will be very troublesome. First you need to add a label at the appropriate position. Set the label's AutoSize to false so that you can adjust the shape and size of the label arbitrarily. Then adjust the BackColor and ForeColor of the label to orange. Finally, place these labels on the edges of the letters to achieve a 3D effect.
Such as “o”:
[image]

Comment: This could easily be done with custom renderers, we just need more information from the OP. You are trying to take a shortcut here with PNG's. This doesn't scale either imagine you have a dozen labels with the same font becomes impractical. Custom renderers deal very well with this by just having 1 class with multiple methods.

Answer (score 0):

So the best option is creating a class to manage this text labels?